# How to solve column res_partner.<column> does not exist in Odoo?

Tags: python, inheritance, odoo, odoo-10

As an example, 'reonp' is a nicely added in model, but when I tried to add a 'gradjanin', Odoo 10 raise an error

[image: image of code/error]

I was trying to restart the server

py

```
class komPartnerrReon(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    reonp = fields.Many2one('kom.reon')
    gradjanin = fields.Boolean('Gradjanin', default=False) #There was an error after adding this line of code
```

error

```
  File "C:\odoo-10.0\odoo\sql_db.py", line 231, in execute
      res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ProgrammingError: column res_partner.gradjanin does not exist
LINE 1: ...id" as "parent_id","res_partner"."name" as "name","res_partn...
```

Comment: Please add the code and error inline instead of using an image.

Comment: You have to update the module

Comment: @khelilimiliana This is internal server error, can not update the model

Comment: @CZoellner Please tell me if I need to add more details, I am new in the this community

Comment: I suggest to add it manually to 'res_partner' using sql querry `ALTER TABLE res_partner ADD COLUMN gradjanin BOOLEAN;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's actually the classic error you get on extending model `res.partner` with new fields.

On starting the Odoo server, every modules python files will be "loaded" so ofcourse your new fields on `res.partner`, too. But that's only on python side or better on the application itself. Now trying to use the application or "loading something in Odoo's webclient" will then try to load data from database, where the new fields don't have the corresponding columns.

For example the login. On login Odoo will load the user, which is logging in. Model `res.users` inherits the whole model `res.partner`, so that Odoo is trying to load `res.partner` data from database. And boom the error.

It can also happen if already logged in. For example in a formular view of a model with chatter. The chatter loads followers, which are partners, so boom the error.

What can you do, to fix that?

**Update the module on server start**

with parameter `-u` (and if more than one database in the system with `-d`)

`odoo -c <path_to_config> -u my_module -d my_database`

**If that's not possible**,

for example in productive systems or because Odoo is started as service, try to start a second instance which will just update the module and stop after that immediately.

`odoo -c <path_to_config> -u my_module -d my_database --max-cron-threads=0 --stop-after-init --no-xmlrpc`

That's like a "self-destroying" headless Odoo instance. The parameter `--no-xmlrpc` will be `--no-http` in Odoo V11+.

**Tell Odoo in the database to update a module/app.**

`UPDATE ir_module_module set state = 'to upgrade' where name = 'my_module';`

After that just restart Odoo.

**Or the tricky way**:

Just go into the Apps menu and open your module/app. Restart Odoo and update the module/app. That's the fastest way, but you guess it, you will sometimes forget to do it. And it's only working before you get the error ;-)

Comment: hahaha thanks a lot, actually i use 'tricky way'
I put '#gradjanin' and restarted the server, opened the Apps menu, my_module, and then deleted '#', restarted the server again and updated it.
Thanks to you, I understand why the error raise
Thank you @CZoeller

Comment: thanks alot , me too i used the tricky way .

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add it manually to 'res_partner' using this SQL query :

```
ALTER TABLE res_partner 
    ADD COLUMN gradjanin BOOLEAN;
```

You face this problem with 'res_users' too, and you don't need to restart the service.

Comment: That is possible, too, but i would use this solution as last possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Before that add depends on manifest for `res.partner`.

```
'depends': ['base'],
```

And update the module. Try again !

Answer (score 0):

As **res_partner** model belongs to odoo **base module** so whenever you inheriting the **base model** to the custom module, try to upgrade the module while starting the **odoo service**, in this case as below:

**Syntax:**
py  "**FILE__PATH_To_odoo-bin**"    --conf  "**FILE__PATH_To_odoo.conf**"  -u **MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_NAME**

**Example:**

py  "C:\odoo13\odoo-bin"    --conf "C:\odoo13\odoo.conf"  **-u my_module**