# Odoo: Invalid field on model

Tags: orm, odoo

I have created a new model in Odoo.

Later, I added a new field to the model but when I try to access that new field (write value) I get the message "Invalid field 'aname' on model 'res.country.state.city"

I checked the database and found the field, it was also found in the model view.
[image]

I thought it might be a cache problem and tried to invalidate the cache `self.env.invalidate_all()` but it's no longer supported in new versions of Odoo.

Comment: Can you share your code?So we can see clearly and help you.

Comment: I know your problem. Uninstall your module and install. That will work.

Comment: Yes, that works. But It's an expensive solution and data might got lost.
There has to be a better alternative.

Comment: You can update crm module .If updating still got error, do it. Update the module on server start with parameter -u (and if more than one database in the system with  odoo -c <path_to_config> -u my_module -d my_database.

Comment: Add crm module in your minifest depends.That may be solve.

Comment: Why CRM? I don't use it. It's a custom module.

Comment: Please share the code of your model and the part where you try to access/write the field.

Comment: This link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816484/how-to-solve-column-res-partner-column-does-not-exist-in-odoo