# how to avoid Error 500 Internal Server Error in odoo15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

i was trying to inherit res.partner and hr.employee,
when i run/restart odoo server i get this error

> Error 500 Internal Server Error

anyway here is my code

1- models/contact.py

```
from odoo import models,fields
class ResPartner(models.Model):
     _inherit= 'res.partner'
         
     con_prenom = fields.Char(string="Prénom")
     con_n_cin = fields.Char(string="N° CIN")
```

2- models/employee.py

```
from odoo import models,fields

class HrEmployee(models.Model):
    _inherit=['hr.employee']

    em_prenom = fields.Char(string="Prénom")
    em_matricule = fields.Char(string="Matricule")
    em_cin = fields.Char(string="CIN")
```

3 - **manifest**.py

```
{
    'name': 'Duplicated Contacts',
    'version': '1.3',
    'category': 'Hidden',
    'description': """
        Duplicated Contacts To Add Fields To Contact view.
        ===================================================
    """,
    'depends': [
        'base',
        'hr'
    ],
    'data': [
        'views/contact.xml',
        'views/employee.xml',
    ],
    'sequence':'-100',
    'demo': [
    ],
    'test': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': True,
    'application': True,
    'license': 'LGPL-3',
}
```

4 - **init**.py

```
from . import models
```

5- models/**init**.py

```
from . import contact
from . import employee
```

Comment: Please show the log error

Comment: that's probably because you've change the partner model. Try add your log and look into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816484/how-to-solve-column-res-partner-column-does-not-exist-in-odoo/53829409#53829409

Answer (score 0):

Without the log the error is probably at this line `_inherit=['hr.employee']` where it should read `_inherit='hr.employee'` without the brackets. To use brackets you need to use `_inherits` with `s` at the end but you would still need the normal `_inherit` and this is a whole another case.