How to solve Field does not exist issue on live db?
This is my code
class ResUserInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    user_signature=fields.Binary(string="Signature")
    user_stamp=fields.Binary(string="Stamp")

    #this is the new field
    is_admin_user = fields.Boolean(string='Is Admin', default=False) 

    def signature_domain(self):
        return [('company_id','=',self.env.company.id)]


    @api.onchange('company_id')
    def get_default_admin(self):
        get_admin_power_group = self.env['res.groups'].sudo().search([('name', '=ilike', 'Admin Power')])
        uid = self.env.uid
        admin = []
        for i in get_admin_power_group.users.ids:
            if uid == i:
               admin.append(i)
        if uid in admin:
            self.is_admin_user = True

Hi, I am Tanvir Islam. I'm facing a problem that is field does not exist. I can solve the issue from the Terminal or from the configuration on Pycharm. But when I'm on live database I'm unable to update the module. And my database is going offline and showing Internal Server Error.
Can any body Help me?
I want to solve the error from the Termius

Does this answer your question? How to solve column res_partner. does not exist in Odoo?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816484/how-to-solve-column-res-partner-column-does-not-exist-in-odoo/53829409#53829409
